# Bash regex matching not working

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, terminal

so I have this function

```
function test(){
 local output="CMD[hahahhaa]"
 if [[ "$output" =~ "/CMD\[.*?\]/" ]]; then
  echo "LOOL"
 else
  echo "$output"
 fi;

}
```

however executing test in command line would output $output instead of "LOOL" despite the fact that the pattern should be matching $output...

what did I do wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to use `.*?` as a non-greedy match? `bash` does not support that Perl-style operator. The forward slashes are also part of Perl's matching syntax, not part of a regular expression itself.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Don't use quotes `""`

```
if [[ "$output" =~ ^CMD\[.*?\]$ ]]; then
```

---

The regex operator `=~` expects an *unquoted* regular expression on its RHS and does only a sub-string match unless the anchors `^` (start of input) and `$` (end of input) are also used to make it match the whole of the LHS.

*Quotations* `""` override this behaviour and force a simple string match instead i.e. the matcher starts looking for all these characters `\[.*?\]` literally.

Comment: This doesn't actually work though, right? Bash doesn't support the lazy modifier.

Comment: I have lost hours debbuging a single line in my script due to this behavior of [['s regex. At first glance, the same result would be got using '...'. What would be de motivation to do that, i.e., to give single quoted power to double quote strings? I can't realize such logic behind.

I found this "inscripition" in bash manual: "Word splitting and pathname expansion  are  not  performed  on  the words between the [[ and ]];..."
Would it be a clue?