# Issue with RegEx in matching timestamp in filename in Linux bash

Tags: regex, linux, bash

I have the following code written to check if my filename ends with some format like given below. It is working when tested online at https://regex101.com/ but not in linux bash. Please help me find out the issue.

Ex:

`timestamp_foramt="^[\s\S]+_INFT_[0-9]{8}_[0-9]{6}[.][\w]+$"
FNAME="Payments.test_INFT_20191218_075918.txt" #example
if [[ ! $FNAME =~ $timestamp_foramt ]]; then echo non-format; else echo format; fi
non-format`

Please help me understand why it is not working in bash. Did I commit something wrong in regex for `timestamp_foramt`?

Comment: Maybe that's because of your quotes as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19327286/2498251)

Comment: May be not. Because, I used the parameter in RHS, double quotes wont be replaced here in run time.

Comment: Yes, it is wrong as POSIX bracket expressions do not support shorthand Perl-like classes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fix the current expression like this:

```
timestamp_foramt="^.+_INFT_[0-9]{8}_[0-9]{6}\.[[:alnum:]_]+$"
FNAME="Payments.test_INFT_20191218_075918.txt" #example
if [[ ! $FNAME =~ $timestamp_foramt ]]; then
  echo 'non-format';
else
  echo 'format';
fi;
```

See the [online Bash demo](https://ideone.com/8PMpxM).

Main points:

- `[\s\S]` can be used in Perl and other NFA regex engines to match any character, in POSIX ERE, used in Bash, you may simply use a `.`
- `\w` is better written as `[[:alnum:]_]` in POSIX ERE as it is more portable to match letters, digits and underscores.

Comment: `\w` is the same as `[[:word:]]` and you should quote `$FNAME`. Btw., the shorthand character classes seem work in my bash if they're not inside a bracket expression `[…]` like `\w+`.

Comment: @Freddy If they are not inside POSIX bracket expressions they may work, yes.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank You so much. It is working!!